# Versions of protocols for BTC and TEST?

Tags: transactions, protocol

I'm dorking around with creating a TEST transaction using libbitcoin's bx command.  Besides setting the inputs and outputs, the bx tx-encode sub-command allows one to specify lock_time and version.  Any idea where one can look to find details about what the current version is for BTC and TEST transactions?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `TX_VERSION = 1` and `TX_LOCK = 0xFFFFFFFF` for mainnet and testnet

Comment: Noticed reading through https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0066.mediawiki#deployment that nVersion is now 3 after the July 4th soft fork.  Should this mean the bx --version argument should now be 3?

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0034.mediawiki#backward-compatibility defines condition for when nVersion was set to 2.

Comment: You're confusing transaction versions with block versions. The answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

`% bx fetch-header -t 365307 -c bx-mainnet.cfg`
header
{
    bits 404063944
    hash 00000000000000000eecb8c5dabfede194627d53fddfdb685103e5317a7e175e
    merkle_tree_hash 8b787ac50ec4e7d3890a917ff196938972f940304badd4f3ebb3c1a480d6eeeb
    nonce 3395429232
    previous_block_hash 00000000000000000641fa532675b3e4fcf879cb5e4358895fa7b87e883b13d9
    time_stamp 1436897984
    **version 3**
}

`% bx fetch-header -t 503223 -c bx-testnet.cfg`
header
{
    bits 486604799
    hash 0000000001eee9c08d12c48f11414c45379e2e7b1b5b5318b012ba0e677609f1
    merkle_tree_hash bb6dc83519a3246adca03a4eeb4d2a7c326693f8c1ed28b6e13824e90ecbde8a
    nonce 561008572
    previous_block_hash 00000000000266ea01bc19141dffa2230e9897259d9ddc058cf41d97328477cb
    time_stamp 1436904967
    **version 3** }

Comment: This is about block versions (which are at 3, since BIP66 took effect). The question was about transaction versions (which have been at 1 since Bitcoin's creation).

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the confusion between Block Versions and Transaction Versions.